# Access denied when trying to import single configuration item

Tags: 8, configuration, importing-exporting

I am using Drupal 8.9.2 and trying to import a view using the Configuration Management UI in the admin. I did this with no issue importing the view from my local dev environment to our dev server, but when I try to do the same thing on our test server, I get "Access Denied".

The way I did this was by going to my local environment and going to Configuration > Development > Configuration synchronization > Export. Then choosing "Single Item". Under "Configuration Type", I chose "View" and then selected my view. I then copied this code and went to my dev server and went to Configuration > Development > Configuration Synchronization > Import and chose "Single Item" and chose "View" for "Configuration type". I pasted my code in and clicked submit and my View was successfully imported and all was well. Now when I do this exact same process on my test server, when I get to the part where I submit my pasted code and click submit, I get:

[image: Access Denied]

Is there a specific directory that I must not have access to on the server? Or Drupal doesn't have access to on the server? I'm not sure what happens behind the scenes during this type of import process. In my settings.php I have this for the config sync stuff:

```
$config_directories['sync'] = '../config/sync';
```

And I checked that directory and it does have read/write permissions. Is that even the directory I need to check as far as permissions go for a single item config import?

Comment: That's clearly a server-related issue. Does the .htaccess exist on dev? How is the vhost configured?

Comment: Wow so I happened across this article. 

https://www.fperkins.com/uncategorized/access-denied-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server-reference.php

It looks like my issue. We are using the Akamai CDN and it looks like it is causing some kind of issue. I'll try to figure it out and post back here.

Comment: Yeah here's another article about this. Akamai is def the culprit. I'll have to get in touch with our admin that takes care of all that stuff.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4492050/access-denied-when-visiting-a-microsoft-website-hosted-on-akamai

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this one was determined to be an Akamai issue for sure. There were some measures that it takes if it thinks it is a denial of service attack and for some reason that was what was happening. Our admin adjusted some settings and the error went away.

THANKS